# Visual Studio ASP.NET Web deploy - Every pages referencing a custom libraries are giving an Error 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, dll, deployment

I have an application in ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1 built with Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.27703.2035). The project itself works 100% fine on localhost. This project contains 3 ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1 libraries that are referenced in the main projects.

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>...</UserSecretsId>
    <WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>0</WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CrmDatabaseManager\CrmDatabaseManager.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SysaidDatabaseManager\SysaidDatabaseManager.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UserInterfaceLibrary\UserInterfaceLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

After publishing the project, it turns out that every pages referencing one of the custom libraries are giving an error 404, all the other pages are working properly.

The problems appeared when I added those libraries to the project.

Is there any reason why libraries would not deploy correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that split the project with libraries did broke path references.

I was hard coding the path and there were no problems with that into the main project. When I splited the project with libraries, it caused an error 404.

To access a file in a libary, you need to do this manipulation first:

1. Right clic on the file > **Properties**
2. On **Build action**, choose **Always copy the file**

Then specifie the path this way on the library:

```
var buildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var filePath = buildDir + @"\fileName.json";

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
   // code here
}
```